# How to extract values from raster stack to point SFC based on attribute R?

Tags: r, gis, raster, r-sf

I would like to extract values from a raster stack to a number of sf point files. The raster stack I'm working with represents daily weather data, and the sf point files represent wildfire footprints, with an attribute corresponding to the day that the point burned. I'd like to extract weather data to these point files, specifically extracting the weather data for the day that the point burned.

I've made some progress in renaming the raster stack layer names to julian day, and subset the raster stack to the day of interest. As it turns out, I need to convert the sf object to a spatial object to get `raster::extract` working. The really tricky part is to subset the raster stack based on the day of burning for *each point*.

I can sort of see how I could iterate through the `sf` point object and `rbind` the results, but is this colossal loop really the only way to get this working?

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
library(lubridate)
```

Next I stack the rasters, which are Arc Grids.

```
fwi.list <- list.files(path = "C:/Example/", pattern="fwi")
fwi.stack <- stack(fwi.list)
crs(fwi.stack) <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"

print(fwi.stack)
    class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 1600, 1900, 3040000, 153  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 3000, 3000  (x, y)
extent     : -2600000, 3100000, -885076, 3914924  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=lcc +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
names      : X121, X122, X123, X124, X125, X126, X127, X128, X129, X130, X131, X132, X133, X134, X135, ... 
min values :    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0, ... 
max values : 1138,  681,  690,  662,  873,  618,  417,  893,  440,  511,  805,  522,  575,  543,  540, ...
```

Here is the `sf` pointfile. The trick will be to assign **fwi** to each point based on the **jday** attre

```
GRID.PT <- st_read("C:/Example/470_2015.shp")
GRID.PT

Simple feature collection with 2126 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -1039086 ymin: 2078687 xmax: -1015336 ymax: 2095187
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    +proj=lcc +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
First 10 features:
                   geometry DOB
1  POINT (-1026836 2095187) 183
2  POINT (-1026336 2095187) 183
3  POINT (-1026086 2095187) 183
4  POINT (-1025836 2095187) 183
5  POINT (-1027336 2094937) 183
6  POINT (-1027086 2094937) 183
7  POINT (-1026836 2094937) 183
8  POINT (-1026586 2094937) 183
9  POINT (-1026086 2094937) 183
10 POINT (-1025836 2094937) 183
```

So, how should I go about this? I'm sure it involves `raster::subset` and `raster::extract`, maybe something like:
`extract(subset(fwi.stack, paste0("X", GRID.PT$DOB[x])), as(GRID.PT, "Spatial"))`

But should I write this as a function and use `lapply`? Or should I use a big loop? Thanks for your help, SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a simple replicable example for this, hopefully it will give some insight into how to solve the issue you're facing.

```
## Set up the raster
test.r <- raster( matrix( nrow=5,
                          ncol=5,
                          data = rep(1,25) 
                          ) 
                  )
extent(test.r) <- c(0,5,0,5)
test.r[] <- 5

## Set up a stack
test.r <- stack(test.r,
                test.r+1,
                test.r+2,
                test.r+3,
                test.r+4)
## Name them in a similar fashion
names(test.r) <- paste0("X",1:5)

## Generate some point data
pts <- SpatialPoints(coords = matrix(ncol=2,
                                     c(rep(seq(0.5,4.5,1),6)
                                       )
                                     )
                     )

## Make it 'sf' for applicability
pts <- as(pts,"sf")

pts$val <- rep(1:5,3)

## Perform lapply that assigns values within
lapply( unique( pts$val ), function(x){

  pt <- pts[ pts$val == x, ]
  rast <- test.r[[ grep( x, names( test.r ) ) ] ]

  pts[ pts$val == x, "rast_val" ] <<- extract( rast, pt )

})

## Or in 1 line

lapply( unique( pts$val ), function(x){

  pts[ pts$val == x, "rast_val" ] <<- extract( test.r[[ grep( x, names( test.r ) ) ] ], 
                                               pts[ pts$val == x, ])

})
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I wasn't sure the square bracket notation would work, but it did. I also learned about <<-, which at first I thought was a typo!

The only change I made to your code was to remove the grep and to substitute with ```subset:raster```, which essentially changes nothing.

Finally, thanks for making a reproducible example, I'll do the same next time.